# Indexing product prices fails

Tags: magento2.3, indexing

We moved out Magento 2 to a new server. All works fine but indexing of the product prices. All other indexers work fine.
An when we run bin/magento indexer:reindex we get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access
>   denied for user 'ku0h8_mag_stagin'@'localhost' (using password: YES),
>   query was: DELETE `price_index`  FROM
>   `catalog_product_index_price_temp` AS `price_index`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON
>   product_entity.entity_id = price_index.entity_id  LEFT JOIN
>   `inventory_stock_1` AS `inventory_stock` ON inventory_stock.sku =
>   product_entity.sku WHERE (inventory_stock.is_salable = 0 OR
>   inventory_stock.is_salable IS NULL) AND (price_index.website_id = 1)
>   AND (price_index.entity_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '8', '9',
>   '29', '30', '31', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '43',
>   '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54',
>   '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65',
>   '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76',
>   '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87',
>   '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100',
>   '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '109', '110', '111', '112',
>   '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122',
>   '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132',
>   '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142',
>   '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152',
>   '153'))

1. localhost is not the host we have set in env.php
2. The table `catalog_product_index_price_temp` does not exists (it's `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`)

I have no idea why Magento uses `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.

Thanks for any help or hint where to start searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First You need to export inventory_stock_1 view from your database then inventory_stock_1.sql file open in any text editor then `'DEFINER='ku0h8_mag_stagin'@'localhost'` and remove from your SQL file now save this SQL file and remove inventory_stock_1 view from your database then now import this saved inventory_stock_1.sql now your issue is fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome! please give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Chirag is correct and works for me as of the time of this posting. If you're using a database management application (e.g. HeidiSQL or Sequel Pro), try the following:

1. Find `inventory_stock_1` in the list of tables
2. Copy the Create Syntax of this view. In Sequel Pro, this is displayed on the Table Info tab.
3. Paste this syntax as a new query. In Sequel Pro, this is the Query tab.
4. Modify the `DEFINER` value to be the username of the DB itself. In my case for my local environment it ended up looking like this: `DEFINER='magento2'@'%'`.
5. Change the name of the view to something other than "inventory_stock_1".
6. Run the query. Delete the old "inventory_stock_1" view and rename the one you just created to "inventory_stock_1".
7. Clear the cache in your local environment, and then reindex. It should work.